# How do I create a table containing a column type of money that is by default set to zero?

Tags: postgresql

What I tried:

```
create table name
(id bigserial not null primary key, cash money not null default 0.0);
```

Why does this code refuse to work? how to correct?

Comment: The `MONEY` data type is a pain to work with. You may want to consider using arbitrary-precision numbers with the `NUMERIC` data type. This gives you a wider selection of useful functions and operators to work with as well as much better language binding support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation generally helps: [Monetary types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-money.html)

> Input is accepted in a variety of formats, including integer and floating-point literals, as well as typical currency formatting, such as '$1,000.00'. Output is generally in the latter form but depends on the locale. ***Non-quoted numeric values can be converted to money by casting the numeric value to text and then money***, for example:
>
> ```
> SELECT 1234::text::money;
> ```